# Javascript array sorting with certain criterias

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Say I have an array with the all the 26 alphabet letters in random order. I know how to sort by alphabetically using the `Array.sort()` function. But how do I sort if I want a particular alphabet say "M" to be the first in the list and then sort alphabetically for the rest of the alphabets.

Currently what I do was splice the "M" from the array and then after sorting I unshift() it back into the list. Is this way of doing ok or is there a more cleaner way to do it?

Example:

**Unsorted**: `['b','c','d','m','a']`

**Sorted**: `['m','a','b','c','d']`

Comment: Add an example of what an unsorted string and a sorted string would look like.

Comment: Your current approach seems better to me than to actually implement your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: Was just about to add what @str said.

Comment: Can there be more than one 'm' in the list? The way you describe your current process you talk about splicing "the M", which makes it sound like there'll only ever be one. (By the way, "alphabets" != "letters".)

Comment: It's unique, so there won't be two 'M's. However, it's dynamic as to which letter will be the priority. I have a config that will determine which letter should be the first in the list.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this way of doing ok or is there a more cleaner way to do it?

It's fine, but if you want, you can customize the sort: `Array#sort` accepts a function that you can use to determine what order two entries should be in. It's called repeatedly by `sort` in the process of sorting.

See comments:

```js
// Create the array
var theArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");

// Sort it
theArray.sort(function(left, right) {
    // `left` and `right` are the two entries to compare.
    // We return a negative number if `left` should come before `right`,
    // 0 if they're equivalent for sorting purposes, or a positive number
    // if `right` should come before `left`.
    // So for M to be in front of all other letters, make sure you handle
    // that in the return value:
    if (left === "M") {
        // Is the right also "M"?
        if (right === "M") {
            // Yes, equivalent for sorting
            return 0;
        }
        // No, left should come first
        return -1;
    }
    if (right === "M") {
        // Right should come first (we know `left` isn't "M")
        return 1;
    }
    // Default comparison
    return left.localeCompare(right);
});

// Show result
console.log(theArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an order object for setting the priority.

```js
var array = ['z', 'r', 's', 'm', 'b', 'q', 'w', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'p', 'o', 't', 'k', 'n', 'i', 'j', 'a', 'y', 'x'];
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var ORDER = { m: 1, M: 1 };
    return !ORDER[a] - !ORDER[b] || a.localeCompare(b);

});
   
console.log(array);
```

Comment: What if you wanted to specify more things in order: `{ m: 1, M: 1, x: 2, w: 3 }`

Comment: you could take something like `(ORDER[a.status] || 0) - (ORDER[b.status] || 0);` with a proper value of the zero default, depending of the wanrted priority.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that scales well if you need more cases rather than just one letter:

```js
var alfabetPriority = "mabcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyz";
var letters = ['b','c','d','m','a'];

letters.sort(function(left, right) {
  return alfabetPriority.indexOf(left) - alfabetPriority.indexOf(right);
});

console.info(letters.join(',')); // gives: m,a,b,c,d
```

What is happening here is that were sorting the characters based on their index in the priority list. This would work with any UTF-8 character. You can change the priority any way you want, including for multiple letters.

The same principle would apply if you were to sort words, in which case you would have an array of words denoting priority rather than a string of characters.

The downside to this might be performance, but unless you're going to do this thousands of times with a huge list of characters that needs to be sorted, you're not going to notice the difference.

Comment: *"All the answer so far don't scale well..."* The above scales worse than any other answer here, by repeatedly re-searching the string by `indexOf`. As for "M" being hardcoded: That was stipulated by the OP.

Comment: Scale as a solution, not performance @T.J.Crowder. For every letter that needs a different priority, the code doesn't have to be amended with an `if-else` construction.

Comment: Okay. The OP asked about making *one* thing special, so it's reasonable (and not remotely "not useful") for answers to answer that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't claim any such thing. Let's leave it to OP what answer he's looking for.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out. As of now, I only determine 1 priority letter. I couldn't manage to think of a way on how to sort what I wanted in the Array.sort() function itself. Therefore, all I could think was splice() and then unshift() it in. Everyone's answer seems good though. I don't think I'm experience enough to judge which is the best however.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from applying a custom comparator to the sort function, you could just move the char later.

```js
var a = ['b','c','d','m','a'];
var b = a.sort();
var c = ["m",...b.join``.replace("m","")];
console.log(c);
```

``` b.join`` ``` converts the array into the string, `.replace("m","")` removes `m`, `...` converts the string back to array (that's the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)) and concatenates `"m"` with it.

Comment: Why the downvote? What have I misunderstood? My answer seems to produce the right output, no?

Comment: dv not from me, but it's not sorting, but reassembling.

Comment: It's just shorter and easier to understand. It's exactly a more "cleaner" way.

Comment: Someone romped through and downvoted everyone's answer except Benny's.